# Can the output from CMake's FindBoost feature be silenced?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

[CMake's FindBoost feature](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html), called using `find_package(Boost ... )`, creates a lot of output that looks like this:

> ```
> -- Boost version: 1.57.0
> -- Found the following Boost libraries:
> --   system
> # ... other libraries ...
> ```

Can this output be silenced?

Setting `set(Boost_DEBUG OFF)` seems to have no effect.

(For those curious about why this might be desirable: our build system is very tightly controlled; we do not intend external developers to be able to build our code in arbitrary environments (and in fact we hard-code the paths to our compilers, libraries, etc in our CMake files). So there's not really any value to seeing this output when building, and it can make it easier for developers to miss information that's actually important.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `QUIET` option for `find_package(Boost...)` call. It will supress "Found the following Boost libraries:" message.

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't think to check the (non-Boost-specific) `find_package` documentation.